# Changing the bounds of a window

Tags: macos, applescript

I need help with Apple script. I don't expert in this matter. The script is this:

```
(*

This Apple script will resize any program window to an exact size and the window is then moved to the center of your screen.
Specify the program name, height and width below and run the script.

Written by Amit Agarwal on December 10, 2013

*)

set theApp to "Finder"
set appHeight to 412
set appWidth to 678

tell application "Finder"
    set screenResolution to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

set screenWidth to item 3 of screenResolution
set screenHeight to item 4 of screenResolution

tell application theApp
    activate
    reopen
    set yAxis to (screenHeight - appHeight) / 2 as integer
    set xAxis to (screenWidth - appWidth) / 2 as integer
    set the bounds of the first window to {xAxis, yAxis, appWidth + xAxis, appHeight + yAxis}
    tell application "Finder" to set the sidebar width of every Finder window to 142
end tell
```

I would like to resize Finder, but without center it in the screen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is, you get the current bounds of the front window. The first two items in the bounds are the starting horizontal point on the x axis and the starting vertical point on the y axis. (in other words, the first two items are the coordinates of the top left corner)
Once you have those, you set new bounds, keeping the first two items in the bounds description the same, and then adding the desired width and height to the second two points to resize the window.

```
set theApp to "Finder"
set appHeight to 412
set appWidth to 678

tell application theApp
    activate
    set {startHoriz, startVert, endHoriz, endVert} to bounds of the first window
    set the bounds of the first window to {startHoriz, startVert, startHoriz + appWidth, startVert + appHeight}
end tell
tell application "Finder" to set the sidebar width of every Finder window to 142
```

If you wanted to move the window all the way to the left, you could change the startHoriz to 1 before setting the bounds of the window.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I sloved in this way:  <set theApp to "Finder"
set appHeight to 412
set appWidth to 678

tell application theApp
 activate
 reopen
 tell application "Finder" to set the sidebar width of every Finder window to 142
end tell

tell application "System Events"
 tell process theApp
  set size of window 1 to {appWidth, appHeight}
 end tell
end tell>         In the end I just had to add Apple Script Editor.app in System Preferences panel: Security and Privacy ➡ Privacy ➡ Accessibility. ︎

Comment: That's fine if it works for you. That won't work as you switch apps.  If the app is scriptable, it is better to avoid using UI scripting.